# Appropriate data structure for combination of options?

Tags: data-structures

I want to do something similar to a product options selector resulting in a single product variant:

For instance, maybe I want a shirt for my favorite sports team and have size, color, and team options groups. I may have various options in each group, some combinations aren’t available, and I could choose in any order, what might be a good structure for this?

I’ve considered a hash table containing various combinations of option values as a key and variant as a value. I’ve considered a trie containing ordered combinations of options leading down to a variant.

Neither really ‘feel’ right.

Comment: Probably depends a bit on what you are trying to achieve. Speed, memory, ease of use...

Comment: The hash table approach sounds like a really reasonable approach. What is your objection? You might consider writing down what you consider the advantages and disadvantages of each approach. Also, consider writing the API to describe how the options selector will interact with your data structure. That will help you refine requirements, which in turn will likely suggest an implementation.